# Javascript/node : Problem using pipe method from a readstream to a http response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

I wanted to pass a text file's content to the server via the `pipe` method via the following code.

```
const {createServer}=require('http');
const {createReadStream}=require('fs');
let server=createServer((request,response)=>{
  response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  let test=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{let src=createReadStream('D:\\Javascript\\JavascriptPlayGround\\text.txt');}
    catch(err){reject(err);}
    resolve(src);
  })
  .then(src=>src.pipe(response)).then(xxx=>response.end('ended'))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
});
server.listen(8000);
```

But I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: src is not defined
    at D:\Javascript\JavascriptPlayGround\server.js:10:13
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` does not exist in the scope where you try to `resolve` it. Also you should just pipe the file-stream to the response and not call `end`. Something like this should work:

```
const {createServer} = require('http');
const {createReadStream} = require('fs');
let server = createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});    
    let test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {            
        try {
            let src = createReadStream('D:\Javascript\JavascriptPlayGround\text.txt');
            resolve(src);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }

    })
        .then(src => src.pipe(response))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

look on your Promise

```
let test=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
      let src=createReadStream('D:\\Javascript\\JavascriptPlayGround\\text.txt');
    }
    catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
    resolve(src);
  })
```

You declare let `src` inside `try` block. When you leave the `try` block `src` became undefined.

Move your `resolve` into the try block

```
let test=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
      let src=createReadStream('D:\\Javascript\\JavascriptPlayGround\\text.txt');
      resolve(src);
    }
    catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  })
```